# How to access the value of a variable outside the callback and load function in store.load?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am working on some code using store.load. This is my example.

```
store.load({
callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    if(success){
            var id = store.getAt(0).data.id;
               }
    });
```

Is there a way to access records.length outside the store.load? 
For example, something like this?

```
store.load({
callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    var id = store.getAt(0).data.id;
 console.log(id); //returns the right value, but cannot use this value outside the load. 
}
});
console.log(id);//returns undefined.
```

Comment: you mean `store.count()`?

Comment: @Digigizmo Sorry i had the wrong variable. I updated the code. I meant retrieving the data from store after we query and get the data. So in my example, I want to get id value.

Comment: But `records` is a collection though right, on what criteria are you isolating a single record?  The API has several methods of retrieving data from a store, such as `getRange`, `find`, `findBy` etc.  [see: docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

Comment: I updated the code again. I'm working on it as well. Anyways.. I understand that store.load is asynchronous so the value of id is not set till the load is done, hence I get the id value as undefined. But is there a way to get the value, outside the function?

Comment: I think you are trying to accomplish too much within the same context - It sounds like whatever functionality is dependant on the change in data should register a `listener` on the store so it can react independently to your callback in a similarly asynchronous fashion.

Comment: @Digigizmo Could you give me an example?

Comment: [sure](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pd7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

```
//Get the store 
var store = Ext.getStore("STORE_NAME")
//now get the data response set in the store
var myDataResponse = store.proxy.reader.rawData
//myDataResponse is the full set of records in the store
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer if this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Im getting an error saying store not defined. The getStore is not able to get the store. Is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: Do you have the store instance, in the location where you need the values inside the store.